# React portal to popup creates instanceof mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Update**

It seems that each new window / iframe / etc has its own set of classes, so instanceof wont work since they aren't actually the same instance.
Not sure about the solution yet though, except for libraries not to use instanceof to check.

**TLDR**: instanceof behaves differently on seemingly same instance/code.

I'm building a React back-office interface that incorporates a map (mapbox) and wanted to add a feature to popout the map so the user can view it on a separate display.

With React.createPortal you can render a component to a window.open element which works beautifully. Except for mapbox.
The issue isn't directly with mapbox though, mapbox renders it's map into a container, you provide this container as a parameter when instantiating the map. Mapbox checks if this container is either a string, or:

`instanceof HTMLElement`

Which works when rendering the Component normally, but fails when rendering the component into a popup/portal, suddenly the **container** check fails.

I've been able to reproduce this in a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/qllpz89w39

**Questions**
- Does anybody have any idea what causes this behavior?
- Is there a way to 'cast' the container to HTMLElement

Source code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Weird bug</h1>
      <PortalTest t="Normal" />
      <WithPortal>
        <PortalTest t="In Portal" />
      </WithPortal>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

function WithPortal({ children }) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const popupWindow = window.open(
    "",
    "test",
    "width=600px,height=640px,left=100,top=100,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"
  );
  if (!popupWindow) {
    return (
      <div style={{ background: "red", padding: "16px", color: "white" }}>
        <h1>Popup blocked</h1>
        <p>Please allow popups for codesandbox to see the full script</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  popupWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, div);
}

function PortalTest({ t }) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("idle");
  const [el, setEl] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      if (el) {
        if (el instanceof HTMLElement) {
          setValue("HTMLElement");
        } else {
          setValue("Unknown");
        }
      }
    },
    [el]
  );

  function setRef(x) {
    setEl(x);
  }

  return (
    <div ref={setRef}>
      <h3>{t}</h3>
      Found ref type: {value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting, so as you said yourself a new window has its own set of classes and their references don't match. I.e.:

```js
window.HTMLElement !== popupWindow.HTMLElement
```

In your codesandbox example you can change the check as follows and you'll see ithe condition will start fulfil in the popup and fail in the main window:

```js
if (el instanceof popupWindow.HTMLElement) {
  setValue("HTMLElement");
} else {
  setValue("Unknown");
}
```

My first intention was to try reassigning `popupWindow.HTMLElement`:

```js
popupWindow.HTMLElement = HTMLElement
```

But it didn't work, so I think the options are:

1. Implement a separate URL which will return the React app with mapbox inside and open it url via `window.open()`
2. Adjust the library `instanceof HTMLElement` check to take into account a window context (which you should somehow pass there)

But I believe the right option is the option #1 since I'm really not sure there won't be other gotchas if you're going to implement such cross-window JS code.

Comment: The beauty of react portal is that all references and actions still work, like responding to a shared mobx store or clicking a Reach Router link. Unfortunately you would lose that with option #1.  As for #2, I reported a 'bug' at the mapbox repo (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8036).